# makeself startup script Permission denied

Tags: linux, sh

I created package.bin file with makeself on CentOS. It was created successfully.However, when i run the bin file on the same machine, i got permission denied error.

I granted 777 and a+x to package.bin file but still got the same error.

```
makeself --gzip ./target/package ./target/package.bin "package" ./install.sh

Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing package.............................
./xxx.bin: line 392: ./install.sh: Permission denied
```

Comment: and what happens if you run this command as sudo?  What's line 392 of install.sh? (smart money is on something that requires escalated privileges)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the permissions of the installation directory.

```
chmod -R 777 /target
```

Comment: Ugh... Why is this a knee-jerk reaction whenever there's a "permissions problem"? It's *always* *much* better to evaluate exactly what the permissions problem is, and fix the specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue resolved by granting permissions to the original sh scripts before these are placed into the package folder in target.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem.

```
makeself.sh ./mysoft mysoft.sh "mysoft description" ./setup.sh

bash mysoft.sh
Verifying archive integrity...  100%   All good.
Uncompressing mysoft desc  100%
mysoft.sh: line 577: ./setup.sh: Permission denied
```

**solved with**

```
 chmod a-x ./mysoft/setup.sh
```